# Partition Data By Year/Month Column without Adding Columns to Result -pyspark/databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a dataframe in pyspark (and databricks) with the following schema structure:

orders schema:

```
submitted_at:timestamp
submitted_yyyy_mm using the format "yyyy-MM"
order_id:string
customer_id:string
sales_rep_id:string
shipping_address_attention:string
shipping_address_address:string
shipping_address_city:string
shipping_address_state:string
shipping_address_zip:integer
ingest_file_name:string
ingested_at:timestamp
```

I need to capture the data in my table in delta lake format, with a partition for every month of the order history reflected in the data of the submitted_yyyy_mm column. I am capturing the data correctly with the exception of two problems. One, my technique is adding two columns (and corresponding data) to the schema (could not figure out how to do the partitioning without adding columns). Two, the partitions correctly capture all the year/months with data, but are missing the year/months without data (requirement is those need to be included also). Specifically, all the months of 2017-2019 should have their own partition (so 36 months). However, my technique only created partitions for those months that actually had orders (which turned out to be 18 of the 36 months of the years 2017-2019).

Here is relevant are of my code:

```
# take the pristine order table and add these two extra columns you should not have in order to get partition structure

df_with_year_and_month = (df_orders
.withColumn("year", F.year(F.col("submitted_yyyy_mm").cast(T.TimestampType())))
.withColumn("month", F.month(F.col("submitted_yyyy_mm").cast(T.TimestampType()))))

# capture the data to the orders table using the year/month partitioning

df_with_year_and_month.write.partitionBy("year", "month").mode("overwrite").format("delta").saveAsTable(orders_table)
```

I would be grateful to anyone who might be able to help me tweak my code to fix the two issues I have the result. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue here. That's just how it works.

You want to partition on year and month. So you should have those values in you data, no way around it. You should also only partition on values where you want to filter on, since this 'causes partition pruning and results in faster queries. It would make no sense to partition on a field without related value.

Also it's totally normal that you don't create partitions where you don't have data for them. Once data is added, the corresponding partition is created if it doesn't exist yet. You don't need it any sooner than that.

Comment: That can't be correct. The year and date column are redundant to the "submitted_yyyy_mm " column. I must get rid of them so that the original schema structure (above) is preserved.

Comment: Thanks though. Educational response definitely, but my dilemma is that the questionI asked is related to training that requires me to partition on a column without adding columns (so your response did therefore not solve my problem). As I said, the "submitted_yyyy_mm" already has the data I need.